# Deleting Realm object causes crash in one func, not in another

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have two nearly identical functions. This one works fine:

```
func deleteEveryDamnThing(){
    let allAccounts = realm.objects(Account.self)
    let allTransactions = realm.objects(Transaction.self)

    try! realm.write {
        realm.delete(allAccounts)
        realm.delete(allTransactions)
    }
    self.activeAcctLabel.text = "No Active Account"
    self.currentBalLabel.text = "$0.00"
    self.highBalLabel.text = "$0.00"
    self.balBarTopConstraint.constant = 505
    self.balanceBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    self.currentBalLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
    self.littleDash.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    self.popNoActiveAccountAlert()
}
```

However, this one:

```
func actuallyDeleteCurrentAccount(){
    let thisAccount = self.currentAccount

    try! realm.write {
        realm.delete(thisAccount)
    }
    self.activeAcctLabel.text = "No Active Account"
    self.currentBalLabel.text = "$0.00"
    self.highBalLabel.text = "$0.00"
    self.balBarTopConstraint.constant = 505
    self.balanceBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    self.currentBalLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
    self.littleDash.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    self.popNoActiveAccountAlert()
}
```

crashes with the explanation:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Object has been deleted or invalidated.'
```

The **second** `func` deletes only `self.currentAccount` from the Realm, while the **first** one deletes **everything** in the Realm, **including** `self.currentAccount`. Both `func`s are in the the same View Controller `class`, and are both called from the same `class`.

I'm using Realm notifications, if that matters.

Anybody have any ideas?

Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem could be that you may be calling the function `actuallyDeleteCurrentAccount()` twice or it's getting erased from somewhere else.

Another reason could be that on your notification token you are assuming your object exists but the object just got deleted.

I recommend you using some prints or breakpoints to narrow down the problem.
Also you can do some checks like this

```
    try! realm.write {
        thisAccount.invalidated == false {
            realm.delete(thisAccount)
        }
        //otherwise the object is already invalidated
    }
```

Then you can use the realm browser to check if the object is in fact deleted.

Comment: Thanks, @David! I tried this, but got the same result. It's like the thing is telling me "I can't do what you're asking, because it's already been done." Of course, the evidence says it has not. I can't use the realm browser, unless I misunderstand, because it can only be used with a simulator. I can't use a simulator, because I'm using my iPhone's camera, and also because the simulator takes about 45 minutes to fire up, if ever. I'll report back if I find a solution...